# How to send custom parameter from jqgrid to rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jqgrid

I use jqgrid in my rails to show data in my web
and I want to decide which data to show depends on which page the user is surfing
here's the code

show.html.erb

```
<%=raw jqgrid("people_list", "people", "/people", 
  [ { :field => "pid", :label => "pid" ,:editable => true},
    { :field => "name", :label => "name" ,:editable => true},
    { :field => "gender", :label => "gender" ,:editable => true},
    { :field => "birthday", :label => "birthday" ,:editable => true}
  ] ,
  {:autowidth=>true,:add => true,:edit => true,:delete => true,:view => true,:edit_url => post_data_people_url,:sortable_rows => 'true'
  }  
)%>
```

people_controller.rb

```
def index
  index_columns ||= [:pid,:name,:gender,:birthday,:school]
  current_page = params[:page] ? params[:page].to_i : 1
  rows_per_page = params[:rows] ? params[:rows].to_i : 10

  conditions={:page => current_page, :per_page => rows_per_page}
  conditions[:order] = params["sidx"] + " " + params["sord"] unless (params[:sidx].blank? || params[:sord].blank?)

  if params[:_search] == "true"
    conditions[:conditions]=filter_by_conditions(index_columns)
  end

  @temp = Person.limit(0).all
  KlassesPeople.where(:klass_id => 1).each do |stu|########
    @temp.concat( Person.where(:id => stu.person_id) )
  end
  @people = @temp.paginate(conditions)
  total_entries=@people.total_entries

  respond_with(@people) do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @people.to_jqgrid_json(index_columns, current_page, rows_per_page, total_entries)}  
  end
end
```

I want to pass the value of klass id from the jqgrid to the controller to determine the value of klass_id in the line with "########"

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to format the code for you but you can use the `postData` parameter to pass a value to your controler every time the jqGrid would get data.

```
postData: { KeyName: KeyValue },
```

If you need to set this value dynamically you can set it via something like:

```
$('#gridName').jqGrid('setGridParam', { postData: { KeyName: KeyValue });
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. And I wonder how I can use this data in controller?

Comment: @EdwardChen Well that would be up to you, but you can change the dataset that you are are returning to the jqGrid based on who is logged in, etc.

Comment: I wrote postData:{test:"test"} in the view and temp = params[:test] then puts temp, however the variable temp is nil.

Comment: @EdwardChen I'm sure you can google for some relevant examples, you should also see the value going out from the jqGrid as part of the POST via Firebug so you can track down if the parameter is not being sent or if you have an issue on your controller.

Comment: By the way, temp = params[:test] and puts temp are in the controller.